# In typescript, is there any way to define global window's extended type via typeof data?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript, is there any way to define global object's extended type via typeof data?

For example 1:

```
window.id = 1
interface window{
   id: typeof window.id;
}
```

For example 2:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  return [...new Set(this)];
};


interface Array<T> {
   // unique(): Array<T>;
  unique(): typeof Array.prototype.unique
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend the `Window` type with an extra custom property, you can do it like this

```js
const id = 1

declare global {
  interface Window {
    id: typeof id
  }
}

window.id = 1 // OK
```

Note that your example wouldn't compile as `id` is referenced directly in its type annotation.

Comment: Nice idea. But how to deal the example 2 in my question?